# Cuda installation, conflicting nvidia drivers seem to not exist

Tags: centos, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I am a relatively new Linux user getting an error about conflicting nvidia drivers when installing cuda on Centos 7:

`Error: nvidia-driver-latest-dkms-libs conflicts with nvidia-x11-drv-libs-515.48.07-1.el7_9.elrepo.x86_64`

I have tried all three installation methods, and they have all failed. The above error is from using the network rpm installation.

I have attempted to remove all previously installed nvidia drivers, and searched in the rpm packages and file system. I don't see any reference to this driver anywhere. I carefully followed all the steps in the installation guide (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#conda) and have scoured the internet. I know Nvidia recommends installing on a fresh version of Linux, but this seems inconvenient.

Comment: Most mainstream distros have both the Nvidia drivers -and- Cuda in their own official repositories so following those Nvidia instructions is often not necessary and can even be counterproductive.

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-centos-7-linux

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, the ```yum install cuda``` step gave the same error. The guide you linked has the nvidia drivers as a dependency, so I'm particularly unclear about why this is a conflict :/

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into similar problems when updating the CUDA drivers. I only had 2 things installed from epel, both used to access hfs and hfsplus volumes. In the end I removed both and thenthe epel repo. This finally made the conflicts go away and the installation worked. This was on CentOS 7.9